# Get links to paragraphs that are not fully numbered

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, chapters

I have my document numbered as follows

- 1
- 1.1
- 1.1.1
- A
- B
- 1.1.2
- A
- B

The subsubsection does not have the complete numbers as the subsection does. However, I would like the links to the subsubsections appear like 1.1.1B. Is it possible to create a command that does this? If I do \ref{label_subsubsectionA}, I just get A. However, how do I get the subsection number of that according subsubsection?
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\Alph{subsubsection}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{The chapter title}
\section{A section title}
\subsection{A subsection title}\label{B}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection level}\label{A}

Current Subsubsection citation "\ref{A}". However, it should appear like 
this: "\ref{B}\ref{A}". 

\end{document}
```

[image]

While I could do this with these two \ref commands, it does result in wrong hyperlinks

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection\Alph{subsubsection}}` will number them they way you mention: `1.1.1B`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Can you please copy your code? It should: a) contain all parts needed to compile for us, b) it should show your current approach. // Just edit your question, copy your code, select it, and click on the "{ }" icon. // Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I think the edits should clarify it. @Werner: I only want to cite the subsubsections like this but not number them like this in the headings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the label `p`refix to include `\thesubsection`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\Alph{subsubsection}}% Subsubsection counter representation
\renewcommand{\p@subsubsection}{\thesubsection}% Subsubsection label prefix
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{The chapter title}
\section{A section title}
\subsection{A subsection title}\label{B}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection level}\label{A}

Current Subsubsection citation: ``\ref{A}''

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. That really was much simpler than I expected